# Is elastic4s 2.3.0 supporting Update By Query Api?

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic4s

I have a question regarding with the Update By Query Api in Elastic Search. I'm using sksamuel.elastic4 2.3.0 library. https://github.com/sksamuel/elastic4s
As i know this library supports "update" api but i couldn't find the update by query functionality. To be sure i would like to ask. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update by query is supported in version 5.0.0
https://github.com/sksamuel/elastic4s/blob/master/elastic4s-core/src/main/scala/com/sksamuel/elastic4s/update/UpdateByQueryDefinition.scala

Comment: link is not valid anymore